# Retrieve Numeric Value out of String SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, select

I have a column `Property` in a table `Order`. We used to store a `dictionary(varchar)` in this column.
We now have a new column (`int`) called `ShoeSize` which has a default value of `0`.

So what I want to achieve is to retrieve only the numeric value out of the `Property` column and update the `ShoeSize` column with that value.

The `Property` column value looks like this:

```
ShoeSize<|$à&£#>15<|@ç§~#>
```

or

```
ShoeSize<|$à&£#>3<|@ç§~#>
```

My question is:
How can I manipulate my SQL in select statement to select only the numeric value of the `Property` column? So in other words, How would I be able to only end up with `15` or `3`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will this format is static. Like the numeric value will always be at this position only ??

Comment: Which database are you using MSSQL, Oracle or MySQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MSSQL and your format is **fixed** then you can try like below

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(50)
SET @str = 'ShoeSize<|$à&£#>15<|@ç§~#>'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('£#>',@str) + 3, CHARINDEX('<|@',@str) - (CHARINDEX('£#>',@str) + 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to extract the numbers from your string.

For example,

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('ShoeSize<|$à&£#>15<|@ç§~#>','[[:digit:]]+') FROM dual;
```

will return 15 to you. Of course, my assumption is that the shoe size in your string will be a number, and your intention is not to collate all digits which occur in your string to come at a number which you will save as shoe size

Comment: OP need it in SQL server, so regexp_substr() function will not work.

Comment: My bad! I somehow missed that he needs it for SQL Server.